# Проблемный кусок кода в jQuery

Tags: jquery

Доброй ночи. Почему после внедрения данного jQuery кода перестала вообще работать отправка формы??? Вот сам код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("form").submit(function(){
        $(":submit", this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
      });
    });
```

При нажатии на кнопку type="submit" она становиться не активной на несколько секунд, только видимо из-за кривизны решения перестает работать отправка формы. Как устранить данную проблему? Зарание спасибо, за ответы.

Comment: А для чего вообще Вы его добавляете? $(":submit", this).attr("disabled", "disabled"); данная строка при отправке формы меняет атрибут disabled у кнопки на disabled т е просто блокирует кнопку.

Comment: Добавил этот код, чтобы нельзя было на кнопку дважды нажать во время отправки данных на сервер, т.е. чтобы не происходило двойной отправки данных...

Comment: @eprivalov1, вы отправляете запрос ajax-ом?

Comment: Нет оправка формы без аякс запроса.

Comment: всё работает, ищите проблему в другом месте. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/ssEZp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не дождался я ответ на свой вопрос в комментарии, но по всей логике, отправляете вы ajax-запрос. Если это действительно так, то для таких целей, есть соответствующие опции:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "handler.php",
    beforeSend: function(){
        // тут делаем кнопку не активной
    },
    complete: function(){
        // тут вернем кнопке обычное состояние
    }
});
```

Comment: Нет оправка формы без аякс запроса, в том то и дело.